# Flask / SQL SQLAlchemy - won't create tables

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been following basic tutorial on how to create a web application with a Postgres DB. Not sure what I'm doing wrong and could use some help.

I've seen two other similar questions here on SO but I am not getting any of the errors that those folks are getting but neither are the tables being created.

I have the following code in app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLAlchemy_DATABASE_URI']=
    'postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/
Height_collector'
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__="data"
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_=db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    height_=db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, email_, height_):
        self.email_=email_
        self.height_=height_
```

the tutorial then has me to to the command prompt, run python, then:

```
from app import db
```

Which returns the following error:

```
'Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. ' 
C:\admSh\FlaskApp\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:794: 
FSADe precation Warning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant 
overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or 
False to suppress this warning.
```

I then type:

```
db.create_all()
```

The tutorial magically shows the tables being created but my tables aren't created. I'm table-less :( Anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

The config properties are case sensitive (actually they will ignore anything not uppercase)

```
app.config['SQLAlchemy_DATABASE_URI']
```

should be

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']
```

Comment: thank you thank you.  I've been going cross-eyed looking at this!

Comment: Not directly related. Ensure app.config['SQLAlchemy_DATABASE_URI'] is before db=SQLAlchemy(app) to avoid 'Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. ' error.